# One of four outside light fixtures (all controlled by same switch) isn't working and it's not the (3) bulbs

Tags: electrical

We have four outside light fixtures in the front of the house, all controlled by a single indoor switch. One of them has stopped working (*so it can't be a circuit breaker issue*).

It's not the bulbs, since they work in the other fixtures and the bulbs from the other fixtures do not work in the faulty fixture.

Does that mean the only thing it could be is the wiring for the faulty fixture?  There's no way all three sockets in the fixture went bad at the same time.

Comment: Do have rats? Check with a multimeter if you have access to one.

Comment: Check for voltage at the bulb that is not working.  If there is no voltage, you are going to have to retrace that romex until the junction box as it has somehow become disconnected/damaged.

Comment: Take one of the working fixtures and install it in place of the non working one.  If it works you know it is a fixture problem and not wiring problem. IF it does not work then you know you have an issue with the wire supplying it. (ALWAYS TURN OFF THE BREAKER WHEN WORKING WITH FIXTURES)

Comment: "*There's no way all three sockets in the fixture went bad at the same time.*" No way ?   That depends on how the fixture is constructed. What is the make and model of the fixture?

Answer (score 3):

Check the voltage at the fixture that isn't working, it could be a bad connection there. If there is no voltage in that box, go to the next fixture box, which is working, and test for loose connections there that would affect the feed to the fixture not working. If there is voltage there and all connections are good, look for a break in the wiring between that fixture box and the fixture box not working.